# Yeoman angular-fullstack ckeditor production

Tags: ckeditor, yeoman, angular-fullstack

I'm using yeoman's angular-fullstack generator with default parameters.

I would like to use ckeditor with https://github.com/lemonde/angular-ckeditor , so I extended my bower.json with the following lines:

> ```
> "ckeditor": "#full/4.4.7",
> "angular-ckeditor": "~0.4.2"
> ```

It works well in development mode ( `grunt serve` ), but it fails in production ( `grunt serve:dist` ). It tries to load `/config.js` and `/skins/moono/editor_gecko.css` and the language file dynamically, but it fails.

Have anybody idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue with ACE editor. What I did is I added override in bower.json

for ace looks like this

```
  "overrides": {
    "ace-builds": {
      "main": [
        "src-noconflict/ace.js",
        "src-noconflict/theme-monokai.js",
        "src-noconflict/worker-javascript.js",
        "src-noconflict/mode-javascript.js"
      ]
    },
```

for you ckeditor config you can specify it in a similar way in the overrides
i.e.

```
 "overrides": {
   "ckeditor": {
     "main": [
       "path/to/your/ckeditor.js",
       "path/to/your/ckeditor/config.js"
     ]
   }
 }
```

for the CSS, not sure but if you check your gruntfile you might come up with a simple solution (i.e. add one more folder to the CSS sources).

If you find a nice CSS solution please post it as it could be helpful to more people ;)